# Physical vs software load balancer?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I just read this article on the history of load balancers:

https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/what-is-load-balancing-24740

going through DNS servers through Cluster IP software based to finally physical devices.

I have also read about HAProxy and nginx in:

https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-5-popular-load-balancers-nginx-haproxy-envoy-traefik-and-alb/

But HAProxy and nginx are server software application that needs to be installed, configured and run like an apache web server.

So how does this fit with the first article that says load balancing is primarily handled by dedicated hardware?

I assume its a combination of both. E.g. in a network you might setup a physical loadbalancer and behind that one or more webservers running e.g. HAProxy for additional load balancing. But its not clear to me when a loadbalancer should be a physical dedicated device and when you can just install e.g. haproxy on a linux server instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Loggly's benchmarks are completely inaccurate, just to get that out of the way. I read that article and thought to myself, this can't be right. So, I followed their article and tried to reproduce it, but got very different results. I have my code and results here on GitHub: https://github.com/NickMRamirez/Proxy-Benchmarks

So, about software vs hardware load balancers. Traditionally, yes, there were rack mounted hardware devices that were load balancers. F5 was king of these devices. Then, HAProxy and NGINX came out and allowed you to proxy traffic via userland software. You can install them onto your own hardware, a VM, a Docker container...whatever. You control the amount of CPU and RAM, depending on your needs.

Of course, you can also buy servers with the load balancing software pre-installed, such as the HAProxy ALOHA. You may also decide to run the load balancer on a dedicated server if you wish.

Side note: F5 acquired NGINX in order to compete in the software load balancer space.

Comment: So if I were to build a fresh infrastructure from the ground up today it would not really make sense to go out and buy dedicated loadbalancer hardware. Instead I would go for a VM/container running e.g. haproxy (except for the ALOHA option you mentioned)?

Comment: There are benefits to virtualization. Including being able to create a VM quickly if one fails or to create snapshots. I think that's most common, rather than provisioning hardware specifically to host the load balancer. Either that, or use Docker containers.